# 80s or 90s movie with evil genie and kids?

Tags: story-identification, magical-creatures, b-movies

I can't recall a movie I saw back in the 90's on TV. I can't recall what happened in all the movie except the last 20 minutes. I recall a girl and a boy,  maybe another boy were inside a cave or under a basement. The kids were like 10-13 years old. I think they were white.

It seemed they were trying to escape, but the genie or troll or some creature stops them. I recall the creature to be big. If I'm not mistaken the girl tells one of the boys to tell the creature some words in some weird language. The creature gets the boy and bites him.  I think that by bitting him, it loses power I can't recall what happened exactly. In the end, they get out and the boy asked the girl what the words meant.  She says *bite me*, *I give you permission to bite me* or something like those words.

I was like 3-4 years old so I can't recall much, but always wondered what movie it was. I don't recall if it was foreign. I have looked over many American movies dealing with fantasy from the late 80's and 90's and trying to see if I recall it but no luck. So I believe it might have been a foreign movie that was dubbed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Obviously if you were that young you may not recall anything else, but just in case the hints might help, you should check out the [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407).  If it was a foreign language film, were there any clues what the original language was?

Comment: I don't recall if it was foreign, I have looked over many American movies dealing with fantasy from the late 80's and 90's and trying to see if I recall it but no luck. So I believe it might have been a foreign movie that was dubbed. The kids were like 10-13 years old.  I think they were white. I recall the creature to be big.

Comment: Is not that one

Answer (score 4):

[*Demon in the Bottle* (1996)](https://imdb.com/title/tt0116074/)?

Here is the plot synopsis from IMDb.com:

> Four teenagers find a lost treasure buried by a 18th century pirate on
>   a desert island. But they accidentally release the monster who lives
>   inside a bottle, keeping the treasure

Here is the complete movie from YouTube, the scene with the boy finding out that the words said to the genie were 'bite me' happens at about 1:14:00. It was a different character saying this to the boy, not the girl.

Comment: Thank you so much, yes it is this movie 

Comment: @myriaidee1sessh43 since you've confirmed this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left. This will show everyone the mystery was solved, and reward both you and the answerer with some reputation :)